# How can I get the "After the Deadline" Libre Office extension to work

Tags: libreoffice

I have installed the "After the Deadline" extension for LibreOffice 3.6.3, but it does not pick up any grammatical errors, either as a wavy blue line while I type, or with a complete spell check of the document. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and thought it could be because of absent Java settings in LibreOffice. It was.

Take a look in `Tools->Options->(Advanced/Java)`, and be sure that some type of Java is selected (either Oracle or OpenJRE).

Answer (score 0):

Select **Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Writing Aids**. Click the **Edit...** button under the **Available language modules** section. Make sure the **After the Deadline** option is selected under the **Grammar** section.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately for me I don't have "After the Deadline" item there despite correctly installed and seemingly active After the Deadline plugin. Something else can go wrong. Otherwise good spot.